# sending an object with nested arrayList of objects post request with form

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I've tried many variants and none of them did not help me. I have front for managing limits:

```
<div layout:fragment="content" style="width: 50%">
    <script>
        function hideEndDate() {
            const checkBox = document.getElementById("has-duration");
            const endDateInput = document.getElementById("end-date");

            if (checkBox.checked) {
                endDateInput.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
                endDateInput.value = null;
            } else {
                endDateInput.removeAttribute("readonly");
            }
        }

        $("body").on("click", "#add_button", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var table = document.getElementById("save-limit-table");
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="id" readonly="readonly" />';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<select name="periodicType" class="form-control">' +
                '<option value="null" hidden="hidden">--Тип переодичности--</option>' +
                '<option th:each="limit : ${T(kg.greentelecom.common.enums.PeriodicType).values()}" th:value="${limit}" th:text="${limit.value}"></option>' +
                '</select>';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="periodicTypeCount" />';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="requestAmountLimit" />';
            cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="totalSumLimit" />';
            cell6.innerHTML = '<button class="btn-delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>';
        });

        function updateServiceSelectReadonly() {
            const limitIdField = document.getElementById("limit-id-field");
            const serviceSelect = document.getElementById("service-select");
            serviceSelect.disabled = (limitIdField.value !== "");
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            updateServiceSelectReadonly();
        });

        function saveLimitConfig() {
            form.submit();
        }

        function deleteRow(button) {
            var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }
    </script>
    <h2> Лимит </h2>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <form id="plan-form" class="form-horizontal" action="#" th:action="@{/limit-config/save}" th:object="${limit}"
          method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add_button" value="add">Добавить</button>
        </div>

        <br/>
        <table id="save-limit-table" class="table table-bordered data-table">
            <thead>
            <tr class="filters">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Тип периодичности</th>
                <th>Кол-во передичности</th>
                <th>Кол-во запросов</th>
                <th>Общая сумма</th>
                <th width="200px">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr data-th-each="detail : ${limit.configDetailModels}">
                <td data-th-text="${detail.id}"><input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${detail.id}" /></td>
                <td data-th-text="${detail.periodicType}">
                    <select id="periodic_type_select" name="periodicType" class="form-control" >
                        <option th:value="null" hidden="hidden">--Тип переодичности--</option>
                        <option th:each="limit : ${T(kg.greentelecom.common.enums.PeriodicType).values()}"
                                th:value="${limit}"
                                th:text="${limit.value}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td data-th-text="${detail.periodicTypeCount}">
                    <input type="number" name="periodicTypeCount" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Кол-во передичности"
                           id="periodic_type_count" />
                </td>
                <td data-th-text="${detail.requestAmountLimit}">
                    <input type="number" name="requestAmountLimit" class="form-control" placeholder="Кол-во запросов"
                           id="request_count" />
                </td>
                <td data-th-text="${detail.totalSumLimit}">
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="totalSumLimit" class="form-control" placeholder="Общая сумма"
                           id="max_total_sum" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've controller for catching request from form:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute LimitConfigModel limitConfigModel) {
        User currentUser = currentUserService.getCurrentUser();

        try {
            if (limitConfigModel.getId() != null) {
                limitConfigModel.setUpdatedBy(currentUser.getId());
                limitConfigService.update(limitConfigModel);
            } else {
                limitConfigModel.setCreatedBy(currentUser.getId());
                limitConfigService.create(limitConfigModel);
            }

            model.addAttribute("message", "Лимит успешно создан");

            return "redirect:/limit-config/index";
        } catch (GTAgentException ex) {
            model.addAttribute("exception", ex.getMessage());
            return "limit/errorLimit";
        }
    }
```

There are my models:

```
public class LimitConfigModel {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private User user;
    private LimitConfigType flowType;
    private Boolean isDefaultConfig;
    private Boolean hasDuration;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date startDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date endDate;
    private Boolean isActive = true;
    private BigDecimal maxAmountPerRequest;
    private Long createdBy;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Long updatedBy;
    private Date updatedAt;
    private List<Long> userIds;
    private Long userId;
    private List<LimitConfigDetailModel> configDetailModels;
}

public class LimitConfigDetailModel {
    private Long id;
    private PeriodicType periodicType;
    private Long periodicTypeCount;
    private Long requestAmountLimit;
    private BigDecimal totalSumLimit;
}
```

What I need to do: I need to collect data from table and insert to list (**configDetailModels**). After making changes and pressing button save I got next:
[image]

Can someone help and explain what I'm doing wrong and why there is no my field in model.